# sklearn svm provides a bad fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I was trying to plot an SVM to my sample data, but I ran into a problem: The plot doesn't seem right at all, which is strange, since I have used sample code from [here](http://mfcabrera.com/files/notebooks/SVM-Slides.html) (more specifically, the "What is happening?" part). Their code works fine for me, so I assume that the problem has something to do with my data. I have noticed that the fit coefficients are really small and this, understandably, destroys the lines.

Here is the reproducible code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib as mpl

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
in_cir = lambda x,y: True if x**2 + y**2 <= 4 else False # Checking if point is in the purple circle
f = lambda x,e: 1.16*x + 0.1 + e                         # True function
ran = np.arange(-5,6)       
lsp = np.linspace(-5,5,170)                              # X1 axis
np.random.seed(69)
dots = f(lsp,[np.random.normal(0,1.5) for i in lsp])     # X2 axis
blue_dots, pur_dots, lsp1, lsp2 = [], [], [], []
for i, x in zip(dots, lsp):
  if in_cir(x,i): pur_dots.append(i); lsp2.append(x)     # Getting all purple dots's X1 and X2
  else: blue_dots.append(i); lsp1.append(x)              # Same for blue ones
plt.scatter(lsp1, blue_dots, color='cornflowerblue')
plt.scatter(lsp2, pur_dots, color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('$X_1$', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('$X_2$', fontsize=15)


x, y = np.array(list(zip(lsp, dots))), np.where( np.array([in_cir(x,i) for x,i in zip(lsp,dots)]) == True, 'p','b' )
                                                        # On two lines above I made x a 2d array
                                                        # of coordinates for each dot
                                                        # And y is a list of 'b' if the corresponding
                                                        # dot is blue and 'p' otherwise

ft = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(x, y)            # Fitting svc

                                                        # Here starts the code from the link
w = ft.coef_[0]
print('w', w)                                           # w components are really small
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (ft.intercept_[0]) / w[1]                 # This is where it all goes wrong

b = ft.support_vectors_[0]
yy_down = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])
b = ft.support_vectors_[-1]
yy_up = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])

plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
plt.plot(xx, yy_down, 'k--')
plt.plot(xx, yy_up, 'k--')


plt.ylim(-5, 5.5)                                      # To make it interpretable
plt.xlim(-5, 4.5)                                      # the plot will be squished because of
plt.show()                                             # high values if removed
```

The output is:

[image: output]

As you can see, the result is tragic. I would be really grateful if someone could explain what am I doing wrong.

---

Edit: I actually managed to pull this off. Here is the code I have written:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
np.random.seed(420)

ran = np.arange(-5,6)
st = 1
b, p = np.array([ (-3+np.random.normal(0,st), -2.5+np.random.normal(0,st)) for i in range(25) ]+\
[ (2.5+np.random.normal(0,st), 3.5+np.random.normal(0,st)) for i in range(25) ]), np.array([ (np.random.normal(0,st), np.random.normal(0,st)) for i in range(50) ])

plt.scatter(b[:,0], b[:,1], color='cornflowerblue')
plt.scatter(p[:,0], p[:,1], color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('$X_1$', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('$X_2$', fontsize=15)


x, y = np.concatenate( (np.concatenate( (b[:25], p) ), b[-25:]) ), [0]*25 + [1]*50 + [0]*25
ft = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(x, y)

by, bx = np.meshgrid([-5, 6], [-5, 6])
bo = ft.decision_function(np.vstack([by.ravel(), bx.ravel()]).T).reshape(bx.shape).T

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5.1, 4.6, 0.01),
                     np.arange(-5.1, 5.6, 0.01))
Z = ft.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
C = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,colors='none', hatches=['.'])
colors=['cornflowerblue', 'magenta']
for j, collection in enumerate(C.collections):
  if j == 0: collection.set_edgecolor(colors[0])
  else: collection.set_edgecolor(colors[1])
plt.contour(bx, by, bo, colors='0', levels=[-1, 0, 1], linestyles=['--', '-', '--'])


plt.ylim(-5, 5.5)
plt.xlim(-5, 4.5)
plt.show()
```

And the result of it is:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to separate with a linear classifier [data which is not linearly separable](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/06/select-support-vector-machine-kernels.html) (i.e. you cannot draw a straight line that separates your two groups). You could use another kernel such as RBF for instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
in_cir = lambda x,y: True if x**2 + y**2 <= 4 else False # Checking if point is in the purple circle
f = lambda x,e: 1.16*x + 0.1 + e                         # True function
ran = np.arange(-5,6)
lsp = np.linspace(-5,5,170)                              # X1 axis
np.random.seed(69)
dots = f(lsp,[np.random.normal(0,1.5) for i in lsp])     # X2 axis
blue_dots, pur_dots, lsp1, lsp2 = [], [], [], []
for i, x in zip(dots, lsp):
  if in_cir(x,i): pur_dots.append(i); lsp2.append(x)     # Getting all purple dots's X1 and X2
  else: blue_dots.append(i); lsp1.append(x)              # Same for blue ones

x, y = np.array(list(zip(lsp, dots))), np.where(np.array([in_cir(x,i) for x,i in zip(lsp,dots)]), 'p','b')

y[y == 'b'] = 0  # replacing letters with integers as the plot_decision_regions function accepts only integers
y[y == 'p'] = 1
y = y.astype(int)

ft = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1).fit(x, y)            # Fitting svc
plot_decision_regions(X=x,
                      y=y,
                      clf=ft,
                      legend=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: SVM with RBF kernel]

Comment: Thanks, this is true. However, I have managed to do it nonetheless. I will update the post in case anyone is interested.